# MySQL MONTH Clause: Want to get Month Name instead of number

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, java

My query is

```
SELECT MONTH(`hire_date`) AS month FROM `emp_tbl`
```

I'm getting output in **Java fx**

```
if(resultSet.next()){
int month = resultset.getInt('month');           // output is like 11

}
```

Then I used **swtich** statement to get month in string. I want output like **'November'** instead of **11**. I **dont want to use switch statment**.
Is there is **any other solution** to get month name as a string instead of a number?

Any other solution besides SWITCH statement?

Comment: Create an array of months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME('2018-11-03');
```

... should give 'November'. So use [`MONTHNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) instead of `MONTH`.

Another option is the [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. This should give the same result as above:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-11-03', '%M');
```

Use `%b` instead of `%M` to get abbreviated month names (Jan, Feb etc).

Comment: See also `DATE_FORMAT(...)`